# Django CreateView - custom get_queryset for only one of the fields

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have a `Mission` model which contains a foreign key to a `Vessel` model, ie

```
class Vessel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Mission(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False, blank=False)
    vessel = models.ForeignKey(to=Vessel, related_name='vessels')
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=((1, 'In progress'),
                                          (2, 'Success'),
                                          (3, 'Partial success'),
                                          (4, 'Failure')))
```

I'm using a `CreateView` to easily let the users create vessels and missions objects. On the `Mission` `CreateView` page there is a drop-down (`<select>`) that lets the user select an existing vessel.

views:

```
class VesselCreate(CreateView):
    model = Vessel
    fields = ['name']

class MissionCreate(CreateView):
    model = Mission
    fields = ['title', 'vessel', 'status']
```

The issue is that on the `Mission` `CreateView` page the vessels are ordered by creation time, and I would like them to be ordered by name.

Where should I override the `get_queryset` method (if at all)? I've tried several places but they made no change on the order of the vessels in the `<select>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not `get_queryset` you want to override here. Rather, you need to create a form, and define a custom queryset on the Vessel field:

```
class MissionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    vessel = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Vessel.objects.all().order_by('name'))
    class Meta:
        model = Mission
        fields = ['title', 'vessel', 'status']

class MissionCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = MissionForm
    model = Mission
```

Comment: Thanks, but that ends up with an error: `MissionCreate is missing a QuerySet. Define MissionCreate.model, MissionCreate.queryset, or override MissionCreate.get_queryset().` So I went ahead and added `model = Mission` to `MissionCreate`, which then complained about `Using ModelFormMixin (base class of MissionCreate) without the 'fields' attribute is prohibited.`. When I added `fields = ['title', 'vessel', 'status']` to `MissionCreate` I didn't get any exceptions, but there was no change in the order of the vessels.

Comment: Sorry, needed to add `model = Mission` to the form meta class. Is that better?

Comment: I'm affraid not, back to the `Missing QuerySet` exception. Might it have something to do with django's version, 1.9.6?

Comment: Argh, apologies, it should be `form_class` on the view. Try it now.